# Edit source files with custom maven archetype

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-archetype

I have created a customer maven archetype and have it setup with some custom requiredProperties:

```xml
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="classPrefix" />
</requiredProperties>
```

I can use that property to name a file, like so:

```
__classPrefix__Config.java
```

My question is can I use that property *inside* the file. I've tried the following two variations but neither work:

```
public class ${classPrefix}Config
public class __classPrefix__Config
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can.
This is a working example for _*classPrefix*_Config.java.

```
#set( $symbol_pound = '#' )
#set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )
#set( $symbol_escape = '\' )
package ${package};

/**
 * this is the prefixed class
 */
public class ${classPrefix}Config{ }
```

Please make sure you have enabled the filtering in the archetype-metadata.xml like this:

```
<fileSet filtered="true">
```

(I am working on maven 3)